# How to set price during products import

Tags: magento-1.9, php, price, product-attribute, import

I don't try to set price attribute during product import. 
Product is inserted into Magento catalog with its name, sku, description but price attribute is empty.
The code I used is the following:

```
$product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$productId = $product_model->getIdBySku($sku);
$categoriesIds = array($categoryId);
if (!$productId) {
    //inserimento
    $product_model
        ->setSku($sku)
        ->setName($name)
        ->setDescription($description)
        ->setShortDescription($shortDescription)
        ->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
        ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
        ->setAttributeSetId(10)
        ->setCategoryIds($categoriesIds)
        ->setPrice($price)
        ->setPrice(11.22) 
        ->setCost(22.33) 
        ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) 
        ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') 
        ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014')
        ->setMsrpEnabled(1)
        ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) 
        ->setMsrp(99.99)
        ->setTaxId(2); 
    $qty = 1;
    try {
        $productId = $product_model->save()->getId();
        $product = $product_model->load($productId);
        $product->setQty($qty);
        $product->setIsInStock(1); //->isInStock(1)
        $product->save();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }
} else {

}
```

Can you help me, please?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

As I think you added price two time and in first time there is no value in $ price. Please remove firset `setPrice($price)` and then try it will work.

Comment: I removed this row but price attribute is already empty

Answer (score 1):

Try with $product_model->setData('price', $price);

Comment: price isn't set..

Comment: First debug whether you are receiving any amount in $price value or try with static value

Comment: $price value arrives from a txt file.. I printed it and its value isn't empty..

Comment: may be reading from text file is the issue it might be converting the price to string try using (float)$price

Comment: the problem remains..

Comment: Then you gotta debug the data that you are posting to the save of product.. check data before and after of  try{
                        $productId = $product_model->save()->getId();

Answer (score 1):

Write below line in if block.

```
 $product_model->setStoreId(0);
 $product_model->setWebsiteId(0);
```

We need to set the store and website Id while importing products.